# Iterate through a PlatonScript array

Tags: for-loop, jplaton

I am developing on the top of the jPlaton platform and I want to declare a 10-element array of integers in PlatonScript.
Then, I want to assign a number to each array position, lets say numbers 1 to 10.
Finally, I want to iterate through this array and calculate and print the double of each array element.

### Array

### |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|

### Output

### |2|4|6|8|10|12|14|16|18|20|

How do I do those "for" loops?

Thanks

Comment: Your output does not make sense. Did you mean 2 instead of 1 for the first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ind:INTEGER
@arr:INTEGER[]
@ind=1
LOOP
    setIndex arr @ind
    IF (@ind>10)
        BREAK

    @arr = @ind
    @ind=@ind+1
ENDLOOP

@dint:INTEGER
@dint=0
@ind=1
LOOP
    setIndex arr @ind
    IF (@ind>10)
        BREAK

    @dint=2*@arr
    @ind=@ind+1
    HTML
        <p>@dint</p>
    ENDHTML
ENDLOOP
```

*Useful array methods*

**setIndex ObjectName IndexValue**
Used in variable of array type
Set the current index of the variable
If index set to -1 then method returns the element count
of the array If index set to 0 then current index set to the last plus one (next empty). If index set to a number smaller or equal to the element count the currennt index is set to the specified number First position index is 1, next is 2 and so on. After we set the current array index we are able to access the current array element using the name of the variable as it was a simple (elementary) one

**clear ObjectName**
Clear the value of the variable. For arrays all the elements of the array are cleared and the array size is set to 0.

**sort ObjectName**
Sort the elements of an array type variable